# Passing shell variable to awk in for-loop

Tags: regex, bash, for-loop, variables, awk

I'm writing a script to print column and row numbers of cells which match a given string and then output it to a text file. The individual `awk` commands work fine in terminal and I've resolved other syntax issues, but .txt that is output still comes up empty. I think I have a problem with passing shell variables to `awk`.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Literal or regex string to find:
read string
echo File path to find string match in:
read filename

echo "Matches for $string were found in the following cells:" > results.txt

for string in filename
do
    awk -v awkvar="$string" -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /awkvar/){print i}}}' $filename >> results.txt | echo -e "\n" >> results.txt
    awk -v awkvar="$string" '/awkvar/{print NR}' $filename >> results.txt | echo -e "\n" >> results.txt
done
```

**Problem Resolved**

I've rewritten the script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prompt for input: 1. enter file name or path that you want searched; 2. enter the literal or regex string
echo File name or path to find matches in:
read file
echo Literal or regex string to find:
read string

# Define variable and test if any matches are to be found; if not, notification is sent to terminal, but if matches exist, their row numbers (as summary rows) and individual column numbers will be output to a .txt file in the home directory. NB: you need to escape minus symbol with brackets, [-], so that it's not confused with an invalid grep option!
matchesFound=$(cat $file | grep -E -c "$string")
if [ $matchesFound -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "No matches exist."
else
    printf "Summary Row No: \n`awk -v awkvar="$string" '$0 ~ awkvar{print NR}' $file`" > results_for_$string.txt
    printf "\nInstance Column No: \n`awk -v awkvar="$string" -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ awkvar){print i}}}' $file`" >> results_for_$string.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `awk` variables inside regexp check pattern, try following instead. You could use `index` function of `awk` and to check if condition try without `/../` way.

```
awk -v awkvar="$string" -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ awkvar){print i}}}' $filename >> results.txt | echo -e "\n" >> results.txt
awk -v awkvar="$string" 'index($0,awkvar){print NR}' $filename >> results.txt | echo -e "\n" >> results.txt
```

This answer deals with only `awk` code shown by OP as per question, to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but the output is still empty….

Comment: @KayGee, As I mentioned I am not sure on your complete requirement(since your question is on awk search only), could you please run only `awk -v awkvar="$string" -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ awkvar){print i}}}' $filename >> results.txt | echo -e "\n" >> results.txt` change $filename to a single value and see what its doing on a single file and let me know then?

Comment: @KayGee, Also filename is a variable if you want to go through its all elements then you could make it an array if its not an array already too.

Comment: It worked great on a single file! Thanks! I just need to find out why it's not working in the for-loop….

Comment: @KayGee, then its confirmed that its your array problem. Just search for how to make an array in shell from a shell variable. For using for loop you should have an array with you, kindly make an array and it should fly then, let me know if any more queries on same, cheers.

Comment: Don't turn a plain variable into an array; read it in directly as an array with e.g. `read -a filenames`, and then use `for string in "${filenames[@]}"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Thank you for adding this note, that's a very Good suggestion, cheers.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, do you mean something like this? ```while read -a filename; do
    for string in "${filenames[@]}"
    do
        echo "Column No. `awk -v awkvar="$string" -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ awkvar){print i}}}' filename`" >> results.txt
        echo "Row No. `awk -v awkvar="$string" 'index($0,awkvar){print NR}' filename`" >> results.txt
    done
done```

Comment: @KayGee You have `filename` in one place, `filenames` in another. Other than that, the loops look ok, but embedding the `awk` commands inside the string passed to an `echo` command looks strange. It might be ok, but I can't tell more without knowing more about what it's supposed to accomplish. BTW, I recommend running your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Right, I fixed that. And thanks for the resource! As for what the script is supposed to do, I want the ```awk``` commands to print column and row numbers of the ```$string``` wherever in the ```filename``` they're to be found and output them to ```result.txt```.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Did you know that your column-finder ```awk``` code still works with regex, but only the row-finder code doesn't? Any roundabout way to make the latter do that as well?

Comment: @KayGee, ok, could you please try changing 2nd code to `awk -v awkvar="$string" '$0 ~awkvar{print NR}' $filename >> results.txt | echo -e "\n" >> results.txt` once, sorry its late night so didn't test it, should work I believe, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Great, now the second row works with regex, too! One more question: whilst the columns are printed for each instance of the string, the row is more of a 'summary row', i.e. it doesn't print row number for each instance and only says in which rows you can find one or more instances in. Any idea if that, too, can be changed (so that I can get the column and row number and group them together for every instance of the string)?